# Checkers playing Neural Network evolved with Genetic Algorithm becomes too sensitive to input data changes

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, overfitting, genetic-algorithms

I recently embarked on a very ambitious project and I have to say it has turned out a lot better than I expected, I succeeded in coding from scratch a neural network that plays checkers at a very acceptable level.

I have one problem though which prevents me from having a stronger AI, I guess some people would call it overfitting, I'm not sure if the term is correct in this situation.

The main issue is that after a certain amout of generations the weights become so great that the smallest change in the state of the board changes the evaluation of it drastically, effectively limiting any kind of nuanced analysis.

A bit more information:

> Neural Network Structure:

Input layer is a series of indipendent layers which take as input a section of the board (1, 0.5, -0.5 and -1 are the inputs taken from the board).

I am using 2 hidden layers of approximately 30 and 10 nodes each, the output node is an evaluation of the board.

> Genetic Algorithm

30 Neural Networks are generated randomly with weights from -0.2 to 0.2, they play 20 games against random opponents and they are rated accordingly (-2 points for a loss, -1 for a draw [120 moves with no winner] and 1 point for a win).

The 15 best are kept and copy/pasted on top of the 15 worst ones, then each weight of the new networks are mutated using the following equation:

> $m' = m * e^{r*0.9} $
>
> $w' = w * m' * r$

Where $m$ is the mutation parameter of that specific weight which starts off at 0.05, $r$ is a random standard Gaussian number and $w$ is the weight.

I hope someone here can help me figure out how to prevent the weights from going haywire after the 40th or so generation.

Comment: Try using activation functions (sigmoid/tanh) after your hidden layers or gradient clipping; these should limit the magnitude of your weight updates.

Comment: @liangjy: There are no gradient calculations involved in this model's training. The weights are mutated randomly instead. For some reason, higher weight individuals are winning initial games, but it is not really clear why to me.

Comment: @liangjy I am using tanh as an activation function for each neuron.

Comment: The algorithm looks as much like particle swarm optimisation as a GA, due to amount of movement in the weights and lack of cross-over between selected parents to create offspring. Given the simplicity of the network and search algorithm, I would not expect much learning to happen at all. How are you measuring results such that you observe the agent "plays checkers at a very acceptable level"?

Comment: @NeilSlater The testing of the actual strength of the network has been one of the issues, thankfully I've had a lot of people willing to test it out, none of them great checkers players by any means but they all reported having a lot of trouble beating the AI. Myself included, I have probably won about 5% of the games I've played against one of the networks in the 30-40th generation, but then again I'm terrible at checkers.
I also tested it against some online checkers engine and it has beaten all of them. Against really advanced engines like cakeMD it struggles a lot in the end game.

Comment: @NeilSlater can you explain why you think that you don't expect much learning to happen at all? I've taken a lot of inspiration from this thesis about Blondie24 (http://eprints.nottingham.ac.uk/12267/1/Thesis.pdf), if you check from page 47 it describes the network and genetic algorithm which are very similar to what I've decided to use.

Comment: @Daniel: Perhaps I am wrong then, but in general GA and other search-driven methods are poor at optimising very high dimension nonlinear parameters. I've not made a checkers player, so perhaps ignore my comment if you have more authoritative source. My gut instinct was that the NN would learn that having more pieces than opponent was good (and thus would aggressively take pieces), through generic weight values, but be quite poor at looking ahead strategically.

Comment: @NeilSlater I do share your concern when it comes to my specific NN, as I  am quite unexperienced on the subject I might have made a lot of mistakes which prevents the NN from really being able to analyze the game. 
But what about the really successful Neural Networks that have been able to play chess or go (AlphaGO) at a really high level? Aren't those essentially the same thing I'm doing just a lot more sophisticated?
Shouldn't my NN also be able to analyze the game and strategize at a very basic level?

Comment: AlphaGo's search method is not GA. It uses a very different approach to train the neural network - essentially it uses an outer reinforcement learning method that helps it estimate reward scores, and then internally the neural network is trained to predict those scores from the game state using gradient-based methods. There are definitely far too many parameters in AlphaGo to use GA to refine them. However, perhaps your network (which I guess has ~ 1500 params) is at a scale where GA works well. In any case, it looks like I don't know enough about this to answer your question sadly

Comment: It may help you get an answer if you explain how you relate the board position evaluation back to the game, and choose a move. Is it as simple as evaluating the results of all possible moves and picking the best resulting next position? Or are you doing some kind of tree search, looking ahead by more than one move, and using the evaluations to help focus the search?

Comment: What is cake md? Link please?

Comment: Stochastic genetic algorithms that use data partially like in stochastic gradient descent have a close performance to SGD though still a bit slower (10 times). Those algorithms can be used with lots of dimensions. See my answer here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/36878/optimising-expensive-functions/37088#37088

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure, I'm not at all an expert on genetic algorithms, so take this with a grain of salt.

First of all, I'm not sure the $r$ parameter in $w'=w*m'*r$ makes sense. You say it's a random standard Gaussian number, which means it could totally change the sign of $w'$. That seems bad. Am I understanding that correctly?

That aside, answering your actual question of controlling weights that get out of control: I would re-normalize the weights after each iteration, e.g. by dividing by its norm: $w'' = w' / ||w'||$. This will allow the weights to shift around, but will keep them from exploding.

Comment: I’m pretty confident this is the answer!